# Is Django multiple unique_together wrongly mapped in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, django-1.11

When I add multiple `unique_together` tuples in my django model, the PostgreSQL DB mapping appears wrong (also according to [a previous SO answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35024190/1588163)). An example follows.

This is my migration:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='FinancialConcept',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ('taxonomy', models.CharField(max_length=128)),
        ('name', models.CharField(max_length=256)),
        ('xbrl_element', models.CharField(max_length=256)),
        ('parent', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='analysis.FinancialConcept')),
    ],
),
migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
    name='financialconcept',
    unique_together=set([('taxonomy', 'name'), ('taxonomy', 'xbrl_element'), ('parent', 'xbrl_element')]),
),
....
```

**which I expected would create three `UNIQUE` indexes**, one for each pair. But instead, what the DB mapping ends up being is this:

```
    Column    |          Type          |                               Modifiers                                
--------------+------------------------+------------------------------    ------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                | not null default nextval('analysis_financialconcept_id_seq'::regclass)
 taxonomy     | character varying(128) | not null
 name         | character varying(256) | not null
 xbrl_element | character varying(256) | not null
 parent_id    | integer                | 
Indexes:
    "analysis_financialconcept_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "analysis_financialconcept_taxonomy_xbrl_element_d8b45254_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (taxonomy, xbrl_element)
    "analysis_financialconcept_parent_id_51fc8021" btree (parent_id)
```

I.e, one of the `UNIQUE` indexes is right, but the other two are missing.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try tuple of tuples?

```
unique_together = (('taxonomy', 'name'), ('taxonomy', 'xbrl_element'), ('parent', 'xbrl_element'))
```

Comment: Just tried but it makes no difference. The bracket is (as is the whole migration) actually generated by django's `makemigration` command.